# É possível chamar o método ExecuteQuery de forma assincrona?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-azure

É possível executar o método `ExecuteQuery` de forma assincrona?

Considere o código a seguir:

```
public virtual MyEntity MyMethod(string parm1, string parm2)
{
    string queryString = TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, parm1),
        TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, parm2));
    TableQuery<MyEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyEntity>().Where(queryString);

    return TenantTnsTable.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

É possível transformar esse método em `async` e chamar o método `ExecuteQuery` usando `await`?

Comment: Por favor especifique que framework/tecnologias esta' a usar, e adicione as tags correspondentes.

Comment: Estou usando azure tables mas não tenho permissão para criar uma nova tag.

Comment: Qando é assim, escreva no corpo da pergunta a tecnologia. Precisa de outra tag? Ou que eu mude essa?

Comment: Não estou familiarizado com Azure Tables, mas em outras tecnologias existe `BeginExecuteQuery`. Não seria este o caso?

Comment: Já tentou botar numa thread separada usando um thread pool?

Comment: @Renanlf pelo que entendi isso seria propriamente async, seria algo como asynchronous sobre synchronous. Eu estava pensando em usar ExecuteSegmentedAsync ou algo do tipo. Ideias?

Comment: Ué, vc vai ter o controle da sua thread de execução, aí vc só precisa definir o comportamento da principal enquanto a outra thread está executando ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o recursos do [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), com ele você consegue rodar qualquer condigo síncrono de forma assíncrona, Segue um exemplo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vai iniciar a criação de entities");
            Vai();
            Console.WriteLine("Criação iniciada de entities");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void Vai()
        {
            var myEntities = await RunWriteLineAsync(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Criação finalizada");
            foreach (var myEntity in myEntities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("myEntity: {0}", myEntity.Nome);
            }
        }

        private static Task<IEnumerable<MyEntity>> RunWriteLineAsync(int total)
        {
            var tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<MyEntity>>();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                var entities = new List<MyEntity>();
                for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
                    entities.Add(new MyEntity { Nome = i.ToString() });
                tcs1.SetResult(entities);
            });

            return tcs1.Task;
        }
    }

    public class MyEntity
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Como você pode ver, eu chamei o método Vai, antes dele eu chamei um WriteLine, e apos ele chamei outro WriteLine.
Se a execução do vai fosse síncrona, o WriteLine apos a chamada do vai, só seria executado apos o código "printar" todas as entidades geradas.

Output do método:

```
Vai iniciar a criação de entities
Criação iniciada de entities
Criação finalizada
myEntity: 0
myEntity: 1
myEntity: 2
myEntity: 3
myEntity: 4
myEntity: 5
myEntity: 6
myEntity: 7
myEntity: 8
myEntity: 9
```

Output do método caso fosse executado de forma síncrona:

```
Vai iniciar a criação de entities
Criação finalizada
myEntity: 0
myEntity: 1
myEntity: 2
myEntity: 3
myEntity: 4
myEntity: 5
myEntity: 6
myEntity: 7
myEntity: 8
myEntity: 9
Criação iniciada de entities
```

Para conferir o segundo output é só substituir o método Vai, por esse:

```
private static void Vai()
{
    var myEntities = RunWriteLineAsync(10);
    myEntities.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Criação finalizada");
    foreach (var myEntity in myEntities.Result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("myEntity: {0}", myEntity.Nome);
    }
}
```